# joomla: Unable to load pathway: administrator

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5, virtuemart

I got the error:
500 - An error has occurred.  Unable to load pathway: administrator
if i click on Virtuemart in Joomla-Backend (1.5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to *500 - An error has occurred.  Unable to load pathway: administrator*, and comment out the lin:

```
mainframe->appendPathWay( $VM_LANG->_('PHPSHOP_CART_TITLE') );
```

All should work fine again.

Answer (score 1):

This maybe help you to solve this problem:

[error 500 - unable to load pathway](http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=430&t=340949)